# How to set the timeout for Amazon SNS (Java)?

Tags: java, amazon-sns

I thought I could set the timeout with the following code, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Am I using "overrideConfiguration" incorrectly?

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.ClientOverrideConfiguration;

ClientOverrideConfiguration conf = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
             .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofNanos(1))
             .build();

SnsClient snsClient = SnsClient().builder() 
             .overrideConfiguration(conf)
             .build();
```

Comment: what request are you then sending to "test" it? Does that request succeed instead of failing as you would expect it to?

Comment: Despite the 1 nanosecond setting, the request succeeds.